# How do I write this template specification when I'm outside the 'class' definition

Tags: c++, templates

This is something that I never ran into before.  Say I have a class that looks like this:

```
template <class T1>
class A
{
   void normal_function();

   template <class T2>
   void templated_function(T2);
}
```

Because of coding standards, I'm not allowed to put the body of `templated_function` inside of the class definitions, i have to have it below (but still in the .h file).

So I have something like this

```
template <class T1>
void A<T1>::normal_function()
{
  ...
}
```

But how do I write the template specification for `templated_function` when it's outside of the class definition?  I tried this, but it didn't seem right to me, and I wasn't surprised when it didn't compile.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void A<T1>::templated_function<T2>(T2 t)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with g++:

```
template<class T1> template<class T2>
void A<T1>::templated_function(T2 t)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: It works with ANY standard compliant compiler.  That's how it's supposed to be done.